# to lock out vs to lock in vs to lock down

Tags: phrasal-verbs

Give, please, a detailed explanation between the next phrasal verbs:

1. to lock out
2. to lock in
3. to lock down

I am especially confused between the meanings of "lock out" and "lock in", they are similar by meaning but have different prepositions, "get in and get out" - it's ok they differ by opposite actions...

Comment: A door has two sides. One side is "in", the other, "out". And there are doors of different kinds:  prison cell doors, house doors, warehouse doors, etc.  I would think that only the preposition **down** might give you some trouble.

Answer (score 5):

**to lock out** - Something is locked and you cannot get into it, so it is *locked* and you are *out* (outside).  You lost your key at the pub and the door to your house is locked, you are *locked out* (outside). You could also *lock* your spouse *out* of the house if you are angry.

This is also commonly used for smartphones and computers in the same way. You may be *locked out* (cannot use the phone/get into the phone) until you enter a code or password or you are *locked out* for a time because you failed multiple times.

**to lock in** - Something is locked and you cannot get out of it, so it is *locked* and you are *in* (inside).  You got into a fight at the pub, the police arrest you and you are *locked in* (inside) a jail cell. You could also *lock* yourself *in* the bathroom if you are angry at your spouse.

This may also mean something of a contract or guarantee.  Something that can be "fixed" or restricted from change.  If you sign the loan contract today then your interest rate is *locked in* at 4% and cannot change.

**to lock down** - One meaning is a combination of *lock in* and *lock out*.  If there is a security crisis at a building, campus, prison etc. it may be *locked down*, or in *lock down*.  No one comes in or out and movement of people inside may be restricted.

Also used in reference to computers or information systems to represent that security controls have been tightened to only allow certain authorized access and functions.

Answer (score 3):

The word *lock* (used as a verb) can be followed by several prepositions.

> to lock out

means to prevent a person/people getting into a room/building/institution

> to lock in

means to prevent a person/people getting out of a room/building/institution

> to lock down

is a phrase used to describe the action by security forces when they surround a building and prevent anyone from entering or leaving, typically in a situation involving terrorists or individuals posing a threat.

> to lock up

means to detain or to imprison when it's used of people,

and to keep under lock and key when it's used of objects.

People can also lock themselves into or out of vehicles and buildings accidentally
and often do.

Answer (score 0):

"To lock out" and "to lock in" differ in a very similar way to "get in" and "get out", actually. If I lock someone *out*, I have locked something such that they cannot get *in* (i.e., they are trapped *outside* the thing I locked). If I lock someone *in*, I have locked something such that they cannot get *out* (i.e., they are trapped *inside* the thing I locked).

This is reflected by the definition in [Cambridge Learner's Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/learner-english/lock-sb-in-out?q=lock%2Bsb%2Bin%252Fout):

> **lock sb in/out**
>   to prevent someone from entering/leaving a room or building by locking the door

but the order they use is confusing -- "lock in" is to prevent from *leaving*, "lock out" is to prevent from *entering*.

You ask for "lock down", but I'm also going to include "lock up", since it's another *lock* + preposition phrasal verb that can be confusing. Unlike "lock in" and "lock out", "lock up" can take either a person or a thing as its object. When you lock *something* up, you're locking all the doors/windows/etc. of something, usually as you leave or go to sleep or something. When you lock *someone* up, you're locking them in somewhere -- usually a prison or something similar from which they cannot escape

"To lock down" typically takes a prison, school, or other important institution (like a governmental facility) as an object, and it describes elevated security measures in which you make the people involved (prisoners, students, etc.) stay locked inside their cells/rooms/etc. during an emergency for safety/security purposes. Police will "lock down" an area after a crime, for instance. It's also often described as "going on lockdown", particularly when it's a school involved, and many schools (at least in the US) have what are called "lockdown drills" where they practice locking down the school in case there's a school shooter or bomb threat.